# parsing HTML tables with irregular column headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

Could I please get some advice on how to parse (in python) a html table such as the one provided in Example 1 here:

https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

As you can see, the header here is hierarchical spanning across multiple rows. I want to get the table parsed so that I can end up with compound column names for each column, i.e.

Mars Produced

Mars Sold

Venus Produced

Venus Sold

Thus far I have attempted to do this with pandas read_html but no luck.

Comment: It might be possible, but irregular or malformed HTML will make reading directly into Pandas via `read_html` difficult. I would do a two-step process, that is 1. parse HTML iteratively using a library like BeatifulSoup 2. create a DataFrame from that output. Here is an example from Chris Albon https://chrisalbon.com/python/beautiful_soup_scrape_table.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually tried beautifulsoup (and it seems like thats the route to go) after ruling out pandas read_html since the latter (thus far) doesn't support handling of multiple header rows this way. With iterative parsing using soup object, I am still unable to accomplish the output I am looking for, the header rows appear misaligned and don't respect the individual child columns.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a table exactly like the one in your example?

Comment: yes, although the formatting of the columns in some cases varies such as the tables provided here for instance: http://ir.approachresources.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=214016&p=irol-newsArticle&ID=2218920